# Multiply two fuzzy numbers

Tags: fuzzy-logic

Can anyone please give me a step by step procedure on how to multiply two fuzzy numbers A and B where

```
        {(x+1)/2     |(-1<x<=1),
uA(x) = {(3-x)/2     |(1<x<=3),
        {0           |otherwise

        {(x-1)/2     |(1<x<=3),
uB(x) = {(5-x)/2     |(3<x<=5),
        {0           |otherwise
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiplication is a bit tricky, even if you have simple triangular membership functions. There is a step-by-step description here: http://debian.fmi.uni-sofia.bg/~cathy/SoftCpu/FUZZY_BOOK/chap5-3.pdf

In most cases, however, the simpler approximation described in example 5.12 (p 8) is probably good enough. In this you just multiply each of the three MF-numbers in one set with the three corresponding numbers in the other. (The results are, however, not very intuitive for numbers close to 0 - Anyone care to comment on/explain this?)